# How the ink drop mix happens in inkjet printer when drops fall on paper?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am studying the inkjet printer in detail. I have come across thermal inkjet printing technology (bubble inkjet technology) and this short discussion below. I want to know the actual mechanism for ink drop mixing on paper when two drops fall in the same place.

Comment: The drops consist of dye or pigment in water. What happens when you mix 2 drops of water?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Superimposed ink droplets exist for a brief time (~tens to hundreds of milliseconds) as flattened hemispheres of liquid on the surface of the paper, where they begin to intermix. That process greatly slows down as they are absorbed into the porous paper surface. this droplet mixing produces a new color according to the *subtractive color* scheme.

The exact hue you get depends on the *order* in which the ink droplets are laid down on the paper, since the first drops down will begin to penetrate the paper *before the mixing process is complete*. This means if you print bidirectionally, you will get systematic *hue shifts* between adjacent print swaths since the colors go down in the opposite order when the traveling printhead reverses direction.

For this reason most color inkjet printing has to be done *unidirectionally*.

Note that even a slight misalignment of the dots on the page will also create significant hue shifts. Since it is impossible to guarantee perfect droplet trajectory out of every nozzle for every different color in an inkjet printhead (the last one I worked on had 3900 nozzles divided between 6 different ink colors) it is necessary to take up to 8 unidirectional passes of the printhead to print one swath because on every swath a different subset of nozzles are turned on for each color so as to average out the hue shifts caused by nozzle nonuniformity.

Even then, the printer that used that printhead contained a color scanning head which "read" a test pattern consisting of every nozzle in every color being printed individually. Any misalignment or trajectory error was then measured by the scanning head for each of the nozzles in the printhead array and mapped into the master control system that formatted each image before a print job started- a process which was repeated each time the printer detected that a new printhead assembly had been installed in the printer.

Furthermore, since the exact hue in any pixel had to be created with an integer number of ink droplets, the "roundoff errors" in hue creation were averaged out by sharing extra color droplets in adjacent pixels, a process called *error diffusion*.

It is an *exceedingly* complex process.

Comment: Well explained sir! Please check your Inbox (killowatt), I mailed you something.